# Using raw input to index xarray DataArrays from Datasets

Tags: python, python-xarray

I'm writing a script that requires the abstraction of a chosen data variable from a read-in xarray dataset. I can't figure out how to do this based on a prompt. I first print the dataset data variables to see how my desired variable is labelled:

```
ds = xr.open_dataset('foo.nc', decode_times=True)
print(ds.data_vars)
```

I now would like to issue a prompt for a user-based selection of their desired variable, given the^ provided list of variable labels:

```
var = input('Please type your preferred data variable label for dataArray selection:')
```

I'm trying to make this user-friendly, although I know that I could simply index this directly in the script (in the example that the variable is called "Et"):

```
da = ds.Et
```

or

```
da = ds['Et']
```

However, in trying to use an object assigned to the string "Et" as a substitute for the indexing^, the process doesn't work:

```
da = ds.var
```

Does anyone have some advice for my situation?

Comment: why not just `ds[var]` ? you can put variables as an index

Comment: I receive the following error: TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: `ds` is supposed to be a data array, i dont think you ran `xr.open_dataset()`

Comment: Thanks. I was wrongly attempting this alternate indexing approach on an erroneous object type because I hadn't cleared my console... Appreciate the help.